# Constructing lists using tidyeval tools (like `!!` and `:=`)

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval

I am looking a way for easy `list` constructing based on `R`'s *tidyeval* framework as defined in the `rlang` package.

Below is what I want to achieve:

```
a <- "item_name"
b <- "item_value"
identical(
    list(!!a := !!b),    # list(!!a := b) is of course also fine
    list(item_name = "item_value")
)
```

What I can obtain at the moment is:

```
list(!!a := !!b)
# output
[[1]]
`:=`(!(!a), !(!b)
```

Alternatively it can get perhaps a little bit better when adding *quosure*:

```
quo(list(!!a := !!b))
# output
<quosure: global>
~list(`:=`("item_name", "item_value"))
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how to proceed further from here.

In other words I would like to have a similar effect like what we can get in the `dplyr` package:

```
transmute(iris, !!a := b)
# first few rows
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species  item_name
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa item_value
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa item_value
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa item_value
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa item_value
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa item_value
6            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa item_value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rlang::list2()` which supports name-unquoting with `:=` and splicing with `!!!`.

Note that you shouldn't unquote the argument itself since `list2()` is not a quoting function, it is just like `list()` with a few more syntactic features:

```
a <- "item_name"
b <- "item_value"

list2(!!a := b)
```

Comment: However, for now it seems to me that it does not matter whether I use `!!b` or just `b`. That is, both approaches seem to be working.

Comment: It's currently superfluous and will stop working in the future.

Comment: Ok, will remeber about that. Thanks!