# Use rlang to create a named list programmatically

Tags: r, rlang

from [Constructing lists using tidyeval tools (like `!!` and `:=`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365814/constructing-lists-using-tidyeval-tools-like-and/), you can do

```
a <- "item_name"
b <- "item_value"

list2(!!a := b)
```

How could I accomplish the same thing itemwise, when there is more than one element?

```
a <- c("item_name1","item_name2")
b <- c("item_value1","item_value2")
```

Comment: `names(b)<-a;as.list(b)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
structure(as.list(b), names=a)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're specifically looking for a "tidyeval" way of doing things, think of the following rule of thumb: where `!!` is used for a single element, `!!!` is its extension to multiple elements.

```
list2( !!!setNames(b, a) )
# $item_name1
# [1] "item_value1"
#
# $item_name2
# [1] "item_value2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

Is this what you're after?

```
map2(a, b, list2)
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] "item_name1"
#
#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] "item_value1"
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] "item_name2"
#
#[[2]][[2]]
#[1] "item_value2"
```

Or perhaps this?

```
map2(a, b, ~list2(!!.x := .y))
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$item_name1
#[1] "item_value1"
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]]$item_name2
#[1] "item_value2"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set multiple names, the rlang package has a `set_names` function

```
a <- c("item_name1","item_name2")
b <- c("item_value1","item_value2")

b %>% rlang::as_list() %>% rlang::set_names(a)
```